# Logging in to console port on Juniper EX2200

Tags: switch, juniper, juniper-junos

I have a Juniper EX2200 with JunOS 10.3R1.9 in a remote location, making it impossible for me to test.

I will be on-site for one day and while there, I would like to login through the console port using a serial to RJ45 cable. I need to know which accounts can login through that interface.

Currently, I have an admin account (username: admin) which I'm able to use to login over SSH. Will I be able to use this account or does it have to be the "root" user? If it has to be root, how can I get/reset the password?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your admin account.

Answer (score 7):

Your Juniper EX2200 console connections will use the same connection you use when logging in remotely.

Getting `root` is completely dependent on your setup.  The following syntax would prevent root login:

```
root-authentication {
    encrypted-password ****disabled****; ## SECRET-DATA
```

This makes it impossible to login via the root account.  If you absolutely needed to get into this account, you would have to perform a [Juniper Password Recovery](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos13.3/topics/task/configuration/authentication-root-password-recovering.html).

Answer (score 4):

On the subject of setting the password for the root account, if your admin account has super-user access then you will not need to go through the full password recovery process.  While logged in with your admin account you can set the password directly:

```
admin@host> edit system
[system]
admin@host# set root-authentication plain-text-password
```

Then follow the prompts to set the password and commit the resulting changes.

To see the permissions associated with the account use `show configuration system login`

```
user admin {
    class super-user;                   
    authentication {
        encrypted-password "$1$t6aUxua2$dhxaXHtnsjn6xluapjx0C0"; ## SECRET-DATA
    }
}
```